# Route53 to RDS not working within a site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS with security groups set up to allow connection from EC2 instances SG's only however for testing and DB deployment I have set the RDS instance to allow public connections (for now).

I have also set up a CNAME record in Route53 to route the unfriendly DNS name to a friendly name. When I access the RDS instance from say Sequel PRO on my local machine I am able to connect using the friendly DNS however, when I use this DNS inside the EC2 instances sites, the connection fails (Unable to connect to DB). I know the connection is working from within the EC2 as if I use the unfriendly DNS it works.

Any thoughts about what I am doing wrong with the connection?

Comment: what does `nslookup [friendly DNS]` return from EC2? public or private IP? What about unfriendly DNS? are they indeed the same when accessed from EC2?

Comment: Hi, both friendly and unfriendly return exactly the same private IP address however the friendly DNS times out whereas the unfriendly has an additional value "non authoritative answer" which has the EC2 instance details and an alias of the unfriendly RDS DNS name. And yep, exactly the same DNS when accessing from Sequel Pro and EC2.

Comment: FYI - The EC2's are sitting behind an ELB...if that helps

Comment: I don't want to put it as an answer (yet), but I have a thought... Does EC2 sit on private subnet? what about RDS? Can EC2 get to internet (that is, is NAT set up properly)? Is it possible that going through friendly DNS involves going through Internet, and EC2 just can't get out... Obviously, speculations - but worth a shot!

Comment: Yes EC2s sit on a private subnet however they are able to access the internet (had to install software). RDS is in private subnet also but again, able to communicate with the outside world (for now). nslookup from my local computer resolves the DNS name correctly for both friendly and unfriendly.

Comment: It's really not that big of a deal if I have to use the unfriendly dns, just thought I was doing something stupid that had an easy (obvious) fix.

Comment: you don't give any details about it but I would guess that the value for the "friendly" address is a public facing IP and the ec2 are on a private subnet and cannot route to this address.

Comment: Haven't I??? We have already established that the EC2 can access the Internet and they are on a private subnet so???...